# How to add shortcut in sql server management studio to filter storedprocedures?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

It is too much hassle to look for a stored procedure or a table when there are more than 500 tables and 800 stored procedures.
I want to create a shortcut so that I can directly search a table or storedprocedure in that database.
Is there any way I can do that in SSMS?

I tried find in files method, but that is definitely not useful in any sense for what I am trying to do.

Comment: What do you mean by look for and search?

Comment: As with many things in SQL Server, the answer is "It depends.". It matters how you intend to 'filter' your search. It matters what you need to find when you search. It may help you to look through the [information_schema.Routines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/routines-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) view.

Comment: If you have used visual studio, then there is this ctrl+shift+t shortcut where we can search any file in all the projects opened in that solution. I am looking for a similar thing with ssms. @P.Salmon

Comment: Try RedGate [SQL Search](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/). It's a free tool.

Comment: Yes. RedGate SQL Search solved my problem to some extent but it still does not directly open the file to edit and execute. @RobertoFerraris